# Query and allocate data to shards based on tags

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running a typical logstash-redis-elasticsearch system to capture all my logs(around 500 GB/day). To my knowledge elasticsearch queries every shard in an index and aggregates the results, but due to the volume of logs per day and the response times needed, I want to query only few shards which of course should be decided on some "tag" in the message. So I'm looking at a way to allocate data to shards based on some tags and query only relevant shards based on the tags. Any leads, references or solutions on how to achieve this ?

I've already looked at [shard allocation filtering](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/allocation/) but that doesn't cater this specific requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routing is the way to go here.

Specify a route option while indexing will cause the document to be routed on a specific shard. See [routing in index API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/index_/).

You can also extract the routing value from a field. See [routing field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/routing-field/).

Don't forget to search with the same routing value. See [routing option in search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/).

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I was looking for. Do you know if we can make `routing` search queries using kibana ?

Comment: I don't think so. May be you can add an issue here: https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana